# Visual Studio 2017 C2027 use of undefined type 'SDL_Texture'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, sdl-2

I moved from compiling my code in gcc to the compiler provided by Visual Studio 2017.

Every time I try to run the application I get the following error:

[image]

Here is the file where I believe the error is coming from:

> Texture.h

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
namespace AcsGameEngine {

class Renderer;

class Texture {
public:
    Texture(const Renderer& renderer);
    Texture(const Renderer& renderer, const std::string&);
    Texture(const Texture& orig) = default;
    virtual ~Texture();

    void load(const std::string&, uint16_t w = 0, uint16_t h = 0) const;
    void load(const char*, uint16_t w = 0, uint16_t h = 0);

    const Renderer& getRenderer() const { return m_renderer; }

    //inline SDL_Texture* getRawPointer() const { return m_texture->get(); }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<SDL_Texture> m_texture;
    const Renderer& m_renderer;

    uint16_t m_width;
    uint16_t m_height;
};
} // namespace AcsGameEngine
```

> Texture.cpp

```
#include "Texture.h"
#include "Renderer.h"
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

namespace AcsGameEngine {

    Texture::Texture(const Renderer &renderer) : m_renderer(renderer) {
    }

    Texture::Texture(const Renderer &renderer, const std::string &p) : Texture(renderer) {
        load(p.c_str());
    }

    Texture::~Texture() {
        if (m_texture != nullptr) {
            SDL_DestroyTexture(m_texture.get());
        }
    }

    void Texture::load(const std::string &path, uint16_t w, uint16_t h) const {
        load(path.c_str());
    }

    void Texture::load(const char *path, uint16_t w, uint16_t h) {
        SDL_Surface *tmp = IMG_Load(path);
        m_texture.reset(SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(m_renderer.getRawPointer(), tmp));
        SDL_FreeSurface(tmp);

        if (m_texture == false) {
            //error
        }

    }

} // namespace AcsGameEngine
```

I don't understand why it is complaining of an undefined type because SDL.h contains the struct SDL_Texture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SDL.h does not contain the definition of `SDL_Texture`. It only contains a forward declaration for it. This is because you are never meant to use the type directly, you are only ever meant to use pointers to it. However, in order to instantiate `std::unique_ptr<SDL_Texture>`, you need the full definition.

But why are you using a `std::unique_ptr` without a custom deleter here anyway, since you just have to manually delete the object with `SDL_DestroyTexture`? That defeats the whole purpose of using a smart pointer. Try this:

```
struct TextureDeleter
{
    void operator()(SDL_Texture* tp) {
        SDL_DestroyTexture(tp);
    }
};

std::unique_ptr<SDL_Texture, TextureDeleter> m_texture;
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I got confused with this as this doesn't seem to compile properly with gcc either.

Answer (score 3):

`SDL_Texture` structure is not declared in SDL.h. It is an internal type and only its forward declaration is available in public interfaces, you can not `delete` it. You should provide the custom deleter to the smart pointer `std::unique_ptr<SDL_Texture, void(SDL_Texture*)> m_texture` and assign later `m_texture = std::unique_ptr(SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(...), SDL_DestroyTexture)`.